# android setdate format "2018-11-14 11:01:02"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, datetime

how could i get this exact format date to fetch in my android via stringDate();
ive using this one but the code not work.

```
      android.text.format.DateFormat df = new android.text.format.DateFormat();
                    df.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a", new java.util.Date());
```

Comment: The code doesn't work because you never use the return value from `format()`.

Comment: Format `2018-11-14 11:01:02` means a 24-hour clock with no AM/PM, which means format string of `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`

Comment: ive use that earlyer but it throws an error even the whole code..

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

this will be the answer i need :D

```
   String.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", 
   java.util.Locale.getDefault()).format(new java.util.Date()));
```

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a [SimpleDateFormatter](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat) instead to format your dates. Below is some Kotlin code that will help you out.

```
    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a")
    println(sdf.format(Date()))
```

Comment: Down-voted because OP wants format `2018-11-14 11:01:02`, i.e a 24-hour clock, which is the entire point of the question.

Comment: can be translate in java? i did'nt know how to use kotlin yet :)